# Notepad++ How to display multiple vertical lines

Tags: notepad, fixed-width

I often work in Notepad++ with files containing several fields of fixed width data.

I know how to display one vertical line at a custom position (Settings/Edit).

I would like to be able to quickly show and hide **multiple** vertical lines, something similar to the import text fixed width wizard in Excel.

Do you know a trick or a plugin to do this in Notepad++?

Comment: [This question](https://superuser.com/questions/1407714/is-there-a-text-editor-which-displays-column-numbers-and-or-displays-text-in-a-g) is related, but does not restrict itself to Notepad++

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### I would like to be able to quickly show and hide multiple vertical lines

As far as I know this is not possible.

The closest thing I've seen is the Notepad++ TextFX plugin **Ruler**:

- Menu TextFx > TextFX Tools > Insert Ruler

  [image]

Notes:

- You can insert multiple rulers at different points in your document (and delete them later), or
- Have a single ruler, clone to other view and have just the ruler in the top window,
- The current column number is displayed in the status bar

Comment: I did not notice the insert ruler and I fear you are right when you say it is not possible to have vertical lines. Ruler helps, but it is not perfect (my files are VERY long).